# Regex to return single line when pattern is matched for a specific text file

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group, python-re

I have multiple text files and wanted to extract the string when a specific pattern matches and append it in a data frame with the file name and the string. In my case multiple same patterns are present in these text files.

```
sample.txt:
"government high school
Govt high school physics department
Employee Designation School Assistant"

What I am getting:
    file         |             Org                      |              Org2 
sample.txt           government high school                   Govt high school physics department
sample.txt           government high school                   Employee Designation School Assistant

What I am looking for:
    file         |             Org                      |              Org2 
sample.txt           government high school                   Govt high school physics department
```

Here is the code I am using :

```
prs_path = "C://Users//subhr//scope_txt//"

df3 = [] 
for file in os.listdir(prs_path):
    Name = None
    with open(prs_path + file) as fd:
        for line in fd:
            line = line.lower()
            match = re.search('r(^.*government.*$)', line, re.I)
            Org = ""
            if match:
                Org = match.group()
                df3.append([file, Org])
            Org2 = ""
            Org3 = ""
            Org = ""
            if match is None:
                match2 = re.search('r(^.*school.*$)|(^.*college.*$)', line,re.I)
                if match2:
                    Org2 = match2.group()
                    df3.append([file, Org, Org2])
                if match2 is None:
                    match3 = re.search('r(^.*power.*$)', line, re.I)
                    if match3:
                        Org3 = match3.group()
                        df3.append([file, Org, Org2, Org3])
                    if match3 is None:
                        continue
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this case `r"^(.*?):$\n\"(.*?) (.*?)$\n(.*?) (.*? .*?) (.*?)$"`

Your input will split in 6 groups, check this for testing.

https://regex101.com/r/UN9cjZ/1

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that was just an example. My actual text files have different lines with different lengths in it :(